# Two weeks in Atlanta and Athens, GA area

Tags: recommendations, atlanta, georgia-usa

I'm planning a 2 week trip (end of Dec / beginning of Jan) to the USA and I will be based in Athens, GA, but I will move a lot between Athens, Snellville and Atlanta.
It's my first time in the USA and I'm glad I will be out of the main touristy areas. What I would like to know are suggestions about what I could see/do. I know this is pretty much personal so here is a small list of things I find interesting:

- Cool country roads
- Cities worth visiting (OK, that's pretty general but I don't know how to put it) in a range of like 4h by car.
- I'm really into literature so if you know of some lit festival or pretty cool library / bookstore (something like City Lights in San Francisco)
- I'm not into military stuff at all but I'd like to visit a shooting range. Maybe this is a somewhat naive question but, are there any shooting ranges that looks "family friendly", not haunted by fanatics?
- Since it's 150 years since the civil war I expect there to be some kind of celebration / events / museums in the vicinity. I found this site, [GACivilWar](http://www.gacivilwar.org), is there anything else I shouldn't miss?
- Typical "south" restaurants and / or places where you can really see what makes the south, the south :-)
- Bars / pubs with live country music
- Cool cabins in the mountains

Comment: Where will you be staying? Are you renting a car (I assume)? Have a nice time! `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to live in Warner Robins, Georgia, so here are some suggestions based on my experience and things I found online.

Northern Georgia has a lot of scenic drives around the Appalachian Mountains. Here are some sites for scenic drives: 
http://www.n-georgia.com/driving_tours.htm 
http://www.trails.com/toptrails.aspx?area=13583 
Stone Mountain in Atlanta has nice history, nature, and views.

Savannah is just outside your 4h range; it's about 4.5 hours away from Athens. Savannah is on the coast and is a really cute town with lots of history.

Quickshot Shooting Range in Atlanta has good reviews, and the bad ones come from people who think it caters too much to newbies, which might be a good thing for you. Governor's Club, a proposed shooting range opening soon, has been in the news for recently getting a liquor license.

Restaurants ranked for their southern food: 
http://www.sheknows.com/living/articles/957315/top-southern-cuisine-restaurants-in-georgia 
http://www.urbanspoon.com/f/149/15632/Georgia/Southern-Soul-Restaurants 
http://www.10best.com/destinations/georgia/atlanta/restaurants/southern/ 
Also the Sundial in Atlanta may be a bit touristy but the views are fantastic. The Vortex is also good for its fun decor and atmosphere.

For live music, here's a good list. The Masquerade and The Tabernacle are music venues, but the Tavern is great, though it gets really crowded. 
http://atlanta.cbslocal.com/top-lists/best-live-music-venues-in-atlanta/